# Access postman datafile variable in node js file with newman

Tags: node.js, postman

I have a data file to pass to the collection of postman using the newman cli.
We can access the data file variable in postman as {{variablename}}.
Is there any way to access the data file variable values in node js file where we are using the newman cli command to run the postman collection.